# Guardar valor em variável depois de curl

Tags: php

Boa tarde.
Estou tentando pegar um valor de uma página (.asp) depois de dar cURL na mesma.

Meu código:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.minhaapi.com.br/script_session.asp?file=api.asp",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

));

$token = curl_exec($curl);
```

Resposta cURL:

```
session={id:7444326,hash:'{2B71B3FB-8FAE-4C7E-BFCF-C9F0EE71D3E3}',customer:{id:8901,name:'cliente1',email:'teste@gmail.com',groupid:0},cart: ...
```

Já que o valor do primeiro id, e a hash muda a cada curl, como posso pegar esses dois valores e guardar numa variável  ? Já tentei a função getStr e não obtive sucesso. Grata.

Tentativa sem sucesso:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.minhaapi.com.br/script_session.asp?file=api.asp",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

));

$token = curl_exec($curl);

$retorno = ltrim($retorno, 'session={');
$retorno = rtrim($retorno, '};');
$retorno = json_decode($token, true);


$id = $retorno['id'];
$hash = $retorno['hash'];
$customer = $retorno['customer'];
echo $hash;
```

Comment: Utilize *Regex*, por exemplo: `preg_match('/(?:id:(\d+)|:'{(.*?)})/', $token, $result); var_dump($result);`

Comment: `preg_match('/(?:id:(\d+)|:'{(.*?)})/'', $token, $result); 
var_dump($result);`

Comment: Me retorna Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in ... on line 130

Comment: `preg_match_all("/(?:id:(\d+)|:'{(.*?)})/", $token, $result); var_dump($result);`

Comment: Retornou isto: array(3) { [0]=> string(40) ":'{B3B3B785-9305-4D78-89B2-FFD677E55938}" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(36) "B3B3B785-9305-4D78-89B2-FFD677E55938" } . Como posso formatar para retornar apenas a hash, ex: "B3B3B785-9305-4D78-89B2-FFD677E55938" ?

Comment: Consegui desta forma: preg_match("/(?:hash:(\d+)|:'{(.*?)})/", $token, $result); 
echo $result[2];

Comment: Obrigada amigo.